# How to work with multiple developer accounts under Enterprise account?

Tags: app-store, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program, app-id, apple-developer

How can we associate developer account to enterprise account in large companies ?

Here my situation :

I have a Enterprise account ($299), with 100 iPhone devices added to it. Since i cant add more devices now, apple recommended me to purchase developer account ($99) and add new additional devices to it.

Here’s my question :

1. If my Ad-hoc profile, Dev Profile and App ID belong to Enterprise account ($299), how can i add the devices from the developer account ($99) to the profiles in Enterprise account($299)?
2. If my new App ID belongs to developer account ($99) and later if i need to sign the app with In-house profile using my Enterprise account ($299), how can i do it?(should i Re-sign it by creating new app ID in my Enterprise account)

PS: I went through several solutions in Stack Overflow but didn't find exact answer. (Please don't mark this as duplicate, i know there are few similar questions)

These are some of the solutions on Stack Overflow:

[Managing IOS Developer AND IOS Enterprise Developer accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406963/managing-ios-developer-and-ios-enterprise-developer-accounts)

[Apple Developer and Enterprise Programs together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897396/apple-developer-and-enterprise-programs-together?rq=1)

[How is a large, spread out company supposed to work with the iOS Developer Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452126/how-is-a-large-spread-out-company-supposed-to-work-with-the-ios-developer-progr?rq=1)

Can someone give a perfect solution for my situation, thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't need to add devices if app was build from enterprise account. I have sent 2 different apps using same account but different provisioning profile to my clients which worked flawlessly without adding their UDIDs.

Comment: I mean to say Ad-hoc profile, not In-house. I have bunch of Ad-hoc profiles on my account and now i want to add devices to them, but there are no spaces to add new devices in portal (reached cap of 100 devices), what would be the best solution to add more devices to the existing Ad-hoc profile?

Answer (score 0):

1. Signing an app with an enterprise profile will let you install it on any device you want (without having to register anything). I think thats the key feature of this account type.
2. Each App ID can only be used once, so you cannot use it in both accounts. You'll have to pick another one then:

   **Example:**
   Dev Account: `com.yourcompany.yourappname` 
   Enterprise Account: `com.yourcompany.yourappname-enterprise` 

   Of course you could use wildcard IDs but, some capabilities wont work then.
3. Basically the enterprise and dev accounts are completely separated. While you can be a member of both accounts with the same Apple ID, and switch them while you are logged in, the accounts themselves have nothing in common with each other.

**Conclusion**

- For In-House-Distribution you can use the enterprise account, without the pain of registering all the devices
- For App-Store Distribution you'll need a separate developer account

Comment: My concern is all about devices that need to be added to the profile, Q1 explains my situation and we cannot use the in-house distribution for all the POC apps that we make, instead we use the Ad-hoc.

Comment: Apple should give an option for Enterprise accounts to reset list Devices in portal round the clock instead of only once in an year. I don't understand why apple doesn't do that

Comment: And I dont really understand, why you register all the devices, if you dont have to :-)

Comment: If you want/have to use the dev account, you can register up to 100 devices per type, and thats it. There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: do you say there's no solution for my Q1?

Comment: basically for larger companies there will me more no. of developers, contractors people will come work for 3-6 months and move on.. but their devices are still included in the dev portal so thats not a good idea

Comment: Maybe I don't exactly got the point of what you want to do. Why don't you just use the enterprise account (there's no limit of devices, as you don't have to register them there)?

Comment: that's when you sign the app using In-house profile but i don't need that. I need to add them to Ad-hoc profile. In Ad-hoc profile you have to add the list of devices. Also, i think according to apple's policy, the In-house should be used only for app dist. among company employs and not contractors also i think it's for beta testing, its for publishing the app among company

Comment: Why? But if you really have to, you'll have to stick with your 100 devices (per type) per account. That's it.

Comment: what if i have 200 developers in my company? and everyone wants to test the app? or at least run the app on their device using Xcode? If 200 people run the app on their phone using Xcode, it will automatically add the devices to portal, but portal cant take more than 100 devices, so what will happen in such cases?

Comment: use the enterprise account? ;-)

Comment: Right now i have enterprise account, but still we don't like to sign the app using In-house for each and every POC app we make also as i said earlier enterprise distribution should be used for dist. app but not for testing the app

Comment: Ok.. there seems to be no solution for your problem. :-)

Comment: Sorry.. what should I say?! Apple has this restriction, you could use the enterprise "workaround" or stick with your 100 devices ;-)

Comment: I'm really not sure of this but someone said that we should not use the Enterprise for Testing purpose....instead should be only used for dist. of production apps, correct me if i'm wrong. Also what if more than 100 ppl are running app on their phone using Xcode? to run app on developers phone his device has to be added the portal right? so what if app needs to be run on 101 device?